# Cannot sync with gradle behind proxy, site is not blocked, opens from browser

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I am trying to open a project (developed in a different machine) with my newly installed `android studio 2.3`. The studio was downloading `gradle-2.1.2.pom` but threw the following error:

> Could not GET
>   'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.1.2/gradle-2.1.2.pom'.
>   Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden

When I try to open the same url above from my browser, it downloads the .pom file, which means the proxy is not blocking it. I have configured the studio with the proxy address and login credentials. Can anyone explain me why is android studio unable to connect to the same site that the browser can open.

Note: I could not find any hint about this in the existing questions about gradle behind proxy, so this new question.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the answer. The solution is to add the certificate to the site https://jcenter.bintray.com in Java (follow [this link](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2012/03/add-list-certficates-java-keystore.html) to do so) and restart the android studio. Basically, the site has to be trusted by java runtime for connecting using `https`.